# Python MySQL vs Ruby MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, ruby

I'm writing a script to be run as a cron and I was wondering, is there any difference in speed between the Ruby MySQL or Python MySQL in terms of speed/efficiency?  Would I be better of just using PHP for this task?

The script will get data from a mysql database with 20+ fields and store them in another table every X amount of minutes.  Not much processing of the data will be necessary.

Comment: Sounds like the mysql server is going to do most of the work so I'm sure the choice of script language doesn't matter.

Comment: If you really want to know, implement it in each of those language and profile it. It sounds like the scripts would be no more than 50 lines in each language. But to be fair, I don't think the choice of language is going to matter.

Comment: Why are you so concerned with the language? If you're not doing any data processing, does it really matter? Have you run benchmarks to indicate that the language will have any affect I what you're doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pick the language you feel most comfortable with. It shouldn't make a noticeable difference.

After writing the application, you can search for bottlenecks and optimize that

Answer (score 3):

Why use external scripts at all? You could just use [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) to call a stored procedure.